# How can i integrate java application with drupal?

Tags: 7

I a new to Drupal. As per my knowledge drupal is based on PHP. How can I get the contents from drupal and use in my java web application?

Is there any way to get the contents from drupal schema which I need complete information of drupal table structure, how contents get saved in tables?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) I just want to clarify that we can only help you with the Drupal side of your issue (i.e. setting Drupal up to expose the data), we can't help you to write any Java code, or help you with connecting a Java app directly to a MySQL database.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very broad question so the answer can only be a broad one...

You can use the [Services module](https://drupal.org/project/services) to expose resources from your site to interested consumers:

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like REST, XMLRPC, JSON, JSON-RPC, SOAP, AMF, etc. This allows a Drupal site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the same callback code.

There's an [Example of Java XML-RPC client with Drupal7 and Services 3.x](https://drupal.org/node/1267522), which (trust me) is the best documentation you'll be able to find.

Comment: It could be a broad answer, but it is also the most correct one, since the OP didn't say anything about the preferred format for the data exchange. Putting some restrictions on the format would allow to use a more specific module, but this answer is still correct.